# Time run down slower in Spritekit update function

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a game in Spritekit, and there's a timer going down that keeps changing in the update function. Sometimes in my game, I change the speed of the physics world, and when that happens I would like for the timer that's going down to also change speed.
To be more specific, I'm changing the speed to 0.5.
So I'd like, in that period for the time to run down at half the speed it's going by.
Here's my code for running down the time. lastSwitch is called in the didMove function.

```
 var lastSwitch = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
 override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    let currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

    let timePassed = currentTime - lastSwitch

    let timeLeft = totalTime - timePassed
    //... bla bla
    time.text = "\(timeLeft)"
 }
```

Comment: When downvoting, please let Pedro know why you downvoted so that Pedro can properly fix his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nodes (scene is a node) have its own speed property, so just set that (`self.speed = 0.5` for half speed).  BTW, I am not sure what you are doing, but I would recommend not doing timing the way you are doing it, since scene time is different then real world time.

Instead, use a custom action:

```
func startTimer()
{
    let duration = 1
    let totalGameTime = SKAction.customAction(withDuration:duration)
                        {
                            [unowned self] (node,elapsedTime) in
                            let timeLeft = duration - elapsedTime
                            self.time.text = "\(timeLeft)"
                        }
    self.run(totalGameTime,withKey:"totalGameTime")
}
```

This way when you use the `speed` property, the timer slows down with it.

So let's say you set your game speed to 0.5.  It will take 2 seconds to complete the action provided because you do duration / scene speed, so 1 / 0.5 which is 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So with that function, what I do basically is I call it in the didMove function?

Comment: whenever you want to start the timer